# Netlogo - layers of matrix (worlds, not matrix in the strict meaning)

Tags: netlogo

I need to have layers of matrix.

i thought it can be done this way:

having n turtles for each patch (in every patch) for representing n layers.
the layers should be grupped in turtle sets.
i will have some comande for showing the k-th layers hinfing the others.

is this a possible solution?

is there a better way?

Comment: Could you instead have patch or turtle variables named, for example, layer1, layer2, ...? Then you could create agentsets for the appropriate layer simply be selecting those agents with layerK set to some value.

Comment: I dont know a priori how many layers will be created . :(

Comment: you could create a single patch or turtle variable and use a list. Note that lists are 0 indexed (so turtles/patches `with item 0 varname = varvalue` or similar would be those in layer 0 etc and if layer number has some intrinsic meaning, you will need to have filler values for nonmeaningful layers)

Comment: But can i increment the size of a list dynamically like in java? with a method like list.add?

Comment: yes, look at the NetLogo dictionary for `lput`

Comment: Have you looked into netlogo3D?